# How does the subString method cause memory overflow

Tags: java, string, oop, java-8, substring

I read somewhere that the String subString method causes memory overflow.How does that happen

I tried to read the documentation but was not able to understand

Comment: Are you sure what you read was accurate? Where did you read it?

Comment: I suspect you are talking about how the _old_ implementation of `substring` could cause a memory _leak_.

Comment: yes yes ,in the old implementation

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if you're processing long strings with sizes close to your available memory. The function subString returns a copy starting from a given index, and this copy uses some memory.

Example: you have 6 GB of memory, and are processing a string that is 4 GB long. You call `myString.substring(1)`, which returns a full copy (minus 1 byte). The system will have to allocate 4 GB for the new copy, but it doesn't have enough. Result: OutOfMemoryError.

Note that strings are usually much, much smaller than available memory, so this is not a common concern. An uncompressed copy of the entire Wikipedia is on the order of 10's of gigabytes, for example, and you're unlikely to load that as a string in Java.

Comment: This is correct in principle, but a string’s length cannot be larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, which means it cannot take up more than roughly 4 GB.

Comment: ( BTW `substring()` is written all lowercases (Java `String`.) Another detail, `substring(0)` returns `this`  - no memory usage (obviously `substring(1)` would do the trick, that is, additionally using almost  same  memory as original) )

Comment: I suspect the OP is talking about how the _old_ implementation of `substring` could cause a memory _leak_, which is correct; it has been _fixed_ to do the thing you describe it doing.

Comment: Every operation that produces a new object could cause an `OutOfMemoryError`. Instead of `myString.substring(1)` you could use `myString + "x"`. Or `myString.split("")`. The possibilities to fill your heap memory are countless. So I’m with @LouisWasserman here. The most likely reason for focusing on `substring` specifically, is the hidden memory occupation of the *old* implementation.

Comment: @VGR actually, a string can not even occupy more than 2GB with the current implementation (as it uses a byte array under the hood since Java 9)

Comment: @Holger How much storage would a String containing Integer.MAX_VALUE occurrences of 'Δ' use?

Comment: @VGR you can not create a string containing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` occurrences of `'Δ'` (anymore). You can create an all-latin-1 string containing (almost) `Integer.MAX_VALUE` characters (if you have enough memory), but adding a single non-latin letter would halve the supported maximum size (see [example on tio.run](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WCEktbhEoZpLAQgKSpNyMpMViksSS4BUWX5mikJuYmaeRnBJUWZeenSsQqImVCUIQEQVihVsFZTOTVHSK0otSE0s0TCMNzA3jjc3MYy3MDLRtAYrr@Wq/f8fAA)), as it would need two bytes per character but the array still can only hold at most (almost) `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bytes…

Comment: @Holger Ah, I see.  I peeked at the source;  even if a String’s content is UTF-16, it’s still stored in a byte array.  You are right, a String can’t be larger than 2 GB.